# Using a WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying and failing miserably to create a simple WHERE NOT EXISTS Clause. Assume the following example,

```
CREATE TABLE #TempUser ( TempUserId INT, TempUserName VARCHAR(50) )

CREATE TABLE #TempData ( TempDataId INT, TempDesc VARCHAR(50) )

CREATE TABLE #TempUserData ( TempUserId INT, TempDataId INT )

INSERT #TempUser ( TempUserId, TempUserName )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Paul' ),
        ( 2, 'Franics' ),
        ( 3, 'Raj' )

INSERT #TempData ( TempDataId, TempDesc )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Test Exists'),
        ( 2, 'Test Not Exists')

INSERT #TempUserData ( TempUserId, TempDataId )
VALUES  ( 1, 1 ),
        ( 1, 2 ),
        ( 2, 1 )

SELECT TU.TempUserId
FROM 
    #TempUser AS TU
    LEFT JOIN #TempUserData AS TUD ON TUD.TempUserId = TU.TempUserId
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TempData AS TD WHERE TD.TempDataId = TUD.TempDataId AND TD.TempDesc LIKE '%Not%')
```

All that I am trying to do is get the list of Users from the #TempUser table who does not have a specific data record, in this case ***Test Not Exists***. The expected result set is UserId 2 and 3, as you can see executing the above will give 1, 2 and 3. So anyone out there who could help me out, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
select TU.TempUserId
from #TempUser as TU
where not exists (
  select 1
  from #TempData as TD
    inner join #TempUserData as TUD 
      on TD.TempDataId = TUD.TempDataId
  where TUD.TempUserId = TU.TempUserId 
    and TD.TempDesc like '%Not%'
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/JJDTM34255

returns:

```
+------------+
| TempUserId |
+------------+
|          2 |
|          3 |
+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT TU.TempUserId
FROM  #TempUser TU
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM #TempUserData TUD JOIN
                       #TempData TD 
                       ON TD.TempDataId = TUD.TempDataId 
                  WHERE TUD.TempUserId = TU.TempUserId AND
                        D.TempDesc LIKE '%Not%'
                 );
```

I suspect your problem is that the first row for user 1 (the one with `TempDataId = 1`) meets the `NOT EXISTS` condition.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to your existing query with one more `left join` and aggregation.

```
SELECT TU.TempUserId
FROM #TempUser AS TU
LEFT JOIN #TempUserData AS TUD ON TUD.TempUserId = TU.TempUserId
LEFT JOIN #TempData AS TD ON TD.TempDataId = TUD.TempDataId AND TD.TempDesc LIKE '%Not%'
GROUP BY TU.TempUserId
HAVING COUNT(TD.TempDesc) = 0
```